# MS Access 2003 - Form question about a control source of a text box

Tags: ms-access, forms, vba, controls, ms-access-2003

How can I write the control source into VBA instead of in the properties window

For example if I have a textbox that divides two amounts in other text boxes, then i put

```
=[textboxA]/[textboxB]
```

in the control source of the properties window. how do i accomplish this in vb so that I can trigger it by events?? i know it is not the same because I already tried that.

Comment: Concerning @Heinzi's answer, for part B, I would be inclined to simply set the control source on the form, rather than through code. It is also important to watch out for Null and divide by zero, if you do not want errors.

Comment: @Remou: it's not unheard of to set the controlsource at runtime (I have reports that change controlsources within each grouping level), so I don't think it's that big a deal to need to do this. I do think that a division is a little odd without any Null removal or checking for zero in the denominator.

Comment: @D W Fenton I am aware that it is not unheard of, it just does not seem necessary in the situation described here. I have been using Access off and on for dunnamany years and have set control sources through code from time to time myself.

Comment: I don't know why it would be unwarranted here, given that the OP asks about setting the controlsource in an event. I don't think we know enough to say that's not appropriate. It is certainly plausible that you'd set a controlsource in the OnCurrent event, for instance.

Comment: The answer remains as the accepted answer showing code that sets the control source, my comment is in addition to the existing, accepted answer, and does not, I think distract from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what exactly you want to do. If you want to put the *current* value of `textboxA / textboxB` into `textboxC`, use:

```
Me!textboxC.Value = Me!textboxA.Value / Me!textboxB.Value
```

On the other hand, if you want to set the `control source` property so that the value is updated automatically, use:

```
Me!textboxC.ControlSource = "=[textboxA]/[textboxB]"
```

*(Code untested, I don't have Access available right now.)*

Comment: The .Value property is redundant, as it's the default property of an Access control.